# QGIS Print composer Label Icon in Legend

Tags: qgis, labeling, legend, print-composer

In a legend of a map I want to label the icon with a number, just as it appears in the map. As example, I have different parcels and every parcel has a number. In the map, the parcels are labelled. In the legend, there only appears the border of the parcel, but not the label inside. Is it possible to get just a random number inside of the icon within the legend?

[image: Example of the legend]

Hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative workaround is to create a symbol with fake labels using font markers. You still won't have all the font styling options that you have in labeling but at least you don't need to resort to adding an overlay textbox in print composer.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Only a workaround, but try placing a textbox on the map in print composer, match the style of the label (font type, bold/italic, but not size, as it will not display the same, usualy you'll need a smaller size) and then overlay the textbox to the legend icon (be sure the textbox is without borders and background). [image: see example below]

It's pretty limited as you can't match all the effects of the label engine (like buffer etc.). 
It's appalling that none of the GIS software I've worked with allows for a simple solution to this! Been looking for a solution for a while...It seems like a pretty simple feature to integrate, hoping to see it in future versions of QGis.